# Validate Django JSONField values are dictionaries

Tags: django

Is there anyway to require that a Django `JSONField` stores dictionary values only? And throws an error on scalar values.

For example, I want the following values to be valid:

```
{}
{"a": 1}
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

And I want the following values to be invalid:

```
"hello world"
True
1
```

`JSONField` currently accepts all of these values, which makes sense because they're all valid json. But I want to change that behavior.

Ideally I want to enforce this at the database level so operations like bulk inserts are protected. But happy to do this at the Django level if that's the best / easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can design a constraint for this, though I would heavily test this to ensure things are working as you'd expect with bulk operations. There's also a [note in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) specifically about `JSONField`:

> Constraints containing JSONField may not raise validation errors as key, index, and path transforms have many database-specific caveats. This may be fully supported later.
>
> You should always check that there are no log messages, in the django.db.models logger, like “Got a database error calling check() on …” to confirm it’s validated properly.

That being said, I think a constraint like this may work.

```py
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = (
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(json_field__startswith="{", lead__isnull=False),
                name="only_single_objects_allowed",
                violation_error_message="Only singular objects are allowed.",
            ),
        )
```

I'm unsure of whether `startswith` will work for a JSONField. Looking at the source, I see no reason why, but I haven't tested this myself.